# QGIS: How to set up a datasource connection to pull locally sourced layers when the name changes

Tags: qgis, template, data-source

I am setting up a template QGIS project which pulls layers from the folder the template is in. The template needs to connect to a raster layer that has a name that slightly changes each time. The name changes depending on the property, ie *property*_NCAS.tif . I want to save a connection that caters for this and connects regardless of the property name.

Currently every time the project opens a pop up window titled "handle Unavailable layers" pops up and requires you to edit the datasource "./project_NCAS.tif" and apply the changes. Is there a way to skip this step?[image: This is the pop up]